# Picture.Insert returns Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to show pictures in excel with the use of a macro.
I have a list of web URLs and I want to see the pictures contained in those links.

Online I found some solutions that suggest to use the Picture.Insert method, but I am not able to make it work.
So far this is what I got:

```
Sub InstallPictures()
  Dim i As Long, v As String
  For i = 2 To 1322
    v = Cells(i, "F").Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Insert (v)
  Next i
End Sub
```

The URL I am using as test is the folllowing: http://cache.lego.com/media/bricks/5/1/4667591.jpg
The error message I receive is the

> Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Any advice on what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It worked when I tested it, although I doubt Lego.com was too keen about me stealing their bandwidth.

Comment: Double check what `v` is actually equal to... maybe there is a space at the end or something. `MsgBox " '" &  v & "' "`

Comment: v is not the problem, since I checked with the debug and also tried with the actual link without success

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your code as simpler as possible. Then test from there:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Dim v As String
    v = "http://cache.lego.com/media/bricks/5/1/4667591.jpg"
    Worksheets(1).Pictures.Insert (v)        
End Sub
```

Does this work for you? If yes, then try to write the `v` in the corresponding cell.

Try again. Does it work? If yes, then try to make the loop!

Try again. Does it work? Insert the `Sheet1` instead of `Worksheets(1)` and so on.

Comment: Hi Vityata, the problem was with Worksheets(Sheet1). When i switched with Worksheet(1) it worked!
Do you know the difference? During my tests, I tried also ActiveSheet but still didn't work

Comment: @J.Snow - obviously you do not have `Sheet1` in your workbook. `Sheet1` is the first default sheet, if you are using English version of Excel. If you are with another version or you have deleted this sheet, it does not exist.

Comment: I do use an English version of Excel 2016. And I do have the Sheet1. I also tried to use active worksheet instead of Sheet1, still didn't work.
 
It did work only with Workbook(1)

Thanks!

Comment: @J.Snow - Write `?Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Name` and see what you are getting in the immediate window.